# How do I manage created content in D&D Character Builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools, dnd-4e-character-builder

I love Character Builder. But I'm wondering how I manage creations specific to my campaign, like gods, boons, magic items or rituals (let alone feats, powers and backgrounds).

What are the ways folks have handled this in their own campaigns? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Character Builder does have a "house rule" function but it's limited. You can make changes and send your campaign file to your players so they can pick up your changes.

The changes are limited, though. It's easy to restrict what options are available, but it's more difficult to add new material. You can add new powers and languages and feats, but they are just text, not "smart" abilities that compute rolls and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little house shape icon in different places, with a little 'H' in it. Click it and you can add custom elements and items.

Comment: Great I'll look for it!

Comment: I've used that to add powers to my characters from another class, but how does it work for custom feats?  I'm assuming they don't have an api or scripting support that allows you to actually make your custom feat add a bonus to your attack powers or anything like that.

Comment: It's just the limited fields you see on the add custom feat dialog I'm afraid. You can always hand edit the XML file and see what you can make appear on the character sheet that way.

Answer (score 1):

Specific only to the installed, legacy character builder, and not the new online one, [CBLoader](https://github.com/CBLoader/CBLoader/wiki/Getting-Started) allows you to add created content (including classes, races, powers, items and  feats, all with appropriate game rules) to the Character Builder.